# How to get rid of sympy substitute error message?

Tags: python, sympy

I have an annoying error message that I cannot figure it out.
The following code (in Python 3) gives a correct results:

```
from sympy import *
x, y, z, t = symbols('x y z t') 
expr = cos(x) + 1
print(expr.subs(x, y))
```

The results are:

```
cos(y) + 1
```

However, when expr is modified or different say,

```
from sympy import *
x, y, z, t = symbols('x y z t') 
expr = 1
print(expr.subs(x, y))
```

The output is the error message saying,

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'subs'
```

How can I fix this?  I need subs to handle symbolic expression and numerical when necessary (say symbolic expression was modified in such a way that result is numerical).
Regards.

Comment: Thanks Carlson for editing my question.  Could not find the code block there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `1` in your second example is not a SymPy number, just a regular Python integer.

You can use the `S()` (or `sympify()`) function to turn it into a SymPy number.

The official docs have a [Gotchas entry](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/gotchas.html#python-numbers-vs-sympy-numbers) that describes your problem and gives a few more examples, and a [description](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#id1) of what `sympify` can do.

Answer (score 1):

`1` is not a Sympy expression. `1` is just a regular Python int. You will need to wrap it in a Sympy Integer if you want to perform substitutions on it. (Also, stop using `import *`.):

```
import sympy

expr = sympy.Integer(1)
```

Note that Sympy Integers display identically to regular ints, so if some `1`s seem to have a `subs` method and others don't, those `1`s might not all be the same type. You can check with `type`:

```
In [14]: x = 1

In [15]: y = sympy.Integer(1)

In [16]: x
Out[16]: 1

In [17]: y
Out[17]: 1

In [18]: type(x)
Out[18]: int

In [19]: type(y)
Out[19]: sympy.core.numbers.One
```

Answer (score 0):

As in the other answers, `1` is not a SymPy integer, it's a Python integer. Therefore it doesn't have SymPy's methods.

You could declare `expr` as one of the following to make it work:

- `expr = S.One`
- `expr = S(1)`
- `expr = Integer(1)`

SymPy integers are instances of the class `Integer`, whereas Python integers are `int` objects.

There is an additional trick to avoid this step: execute `isympy -i`. The `-i` parameter adds an additional input layer that replaces all digits with `Integer(digits)` objects, as an example:

```
In [1]: 1
Out[1]: 1

In [2]: In[1]
Out[2]: u'Integer (1 )'
```

That is, inspecting with *IPython* what the input 1 is, gives `u'Integer (1 )'`.